# How to execute different error messages depending on where a query failed in a transaction in pg-promise?

Tags: pg-promise

how can I execute varying error messages depending on where a query failed, triggering a rollback, in my transaction?

I'll be using the sample code from the documentation:

```js
db.tx(t => {
    // creating a sequence of transaction queries:
    const q1 = t.none(query);
    const q2 = t.one(query);
    const q3 = t.one(query);

    // returning a promise that determines a successful transaction:
    return t.batch([q1, q2, q3]); // all of the queries are to be resolved;
})
    .then(data => {
        // success, COMMIT was executed
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // failure, ROLLBACK was executed
    });
```

Preferred output is the following:

- if the transaction failed in q1:

```js
res.json({error: true, message:"q1 failed"})
```

- if the transaction failed in q2:

```js
res.json({error: true, message:"q2 failed"})
```

- if the transaction failed in q3:

```js
res.json({error: true, message:"q2 failed"}), etc.
```

What I'm thinking is using a Switch statement to determine what error message to execute, although I don't have an idea on how to *know* what query failed in the transaction.

Thank you for your help!

P.S. I recently migrated from node-pg to pg-promise (which is why I'm a bit new with the API) due to having a hard time with transactions as recommended in my previous posts, and yeah, pg-promise made a lot of things easier the 1 day worth of refactoring code is worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using method [batch](http://vitaly-t.github.io/spex/global.html#batch), you get [BatchError](http://vitaly-t.github.io/spex/errors.BatchError.html) thrown when the method fails, which has useful property `data`, among others:

```js
.catch(err => {
    // find index of the first failed query:
    const errIdx = err.data.findIndex(e => !e.success);

    // do what you want here, based on the index;
});
```

Note that inside such error handler, `err.data[errIdx].result` is the same as `err.first`, representing the first error that occurred.

Comment: It worked, thank you! If I may follow up though, is there a way for me to forcibly terminate a transaction based on the results of one of the queries? e.g. if q1 returned an empty array, stop the transaction and rollback everything. Thank you!

Comment: Just throw an error inside the transaction function, and that's all :)

Comment: Though you should use the `async` syntax then perhaps ;)

Comment: That... actually makes sennse because we're catching "error" , so I can just return ```error``` when the condition gets triggered.

And it works! Thank you! :))

Comment: OR, I just used ```throw "message"``` . Thank you nonetheless! :DD